# ECG filter in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, python-3.x

I'm new to Python, I hope not to obvious questions, need some urgent help.

I have a file with the signal, I have to answer the questions:
a) present a statistical description of the original signal (maximum, minimum, average and standard deviation).
b) Filter the signal to be observed with minimum noise and high frequency "base line wandering". Make the plot of this signal [Create subplot 1]
c) Provide a description of statistical signal filtardo.

I've done this code:

```
max_s = max (s)
min_s = min (s)
std_s = std (s)
mean_s = mean (s)

fil = s
sf = ni.filter.bandpass (fil, 1., 45., fs = 495)
subplot (4, 1, 1)
plot (t, n)

max_sf = max (sf)
min_sf = min (sf)
std_sf = std (sf)
mean_sf = mean (sf)
```

but still is not working, need help

Comment: What have you tried? This site's Q and A format works best if you've already tried to solve the problem and have run into a problem. If you haven't started, give it a try first, then come back ask about specific issues.

Comment: For starters you'll have to read the file first. If it is a standard sound file you can probably find a Python module to read it. If it is a standard for ECGs google the name of the standard and 'python' and maybe there' already a module for that.  Otherwise you need to look into the 'struct' module to unpack the binary data. Once you have the data the 'numpy' and 'scipy' modules will have filters.

Comment: More details in the question

Answer (score 2):

For the high frequency noise I'd suggest a fir filter. See for instance:

http://mpastell.com/2010/01/18/fir-with-scipy/

You want a low pass filter which also blocks 60hz noise.

For the baseline wandering I'd suggest incorporating the wandering into whatever algorithm you are using to analyse the data.

Comment: More details in the question